# Updating React component state in Jasmine Test

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a relatively simple React component that renders a list based on its state.  Then I have a karma/jasmine test that renders the component, sets its state, and checks that the correct markup is rendered.

The problem I'm running into is that every time I do a `setState({})` or `forceUpdate()` on my component, I'm getting an error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'deepestAncestor.firstChild')
        at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/bower_components/react/react.js:10314
```

What's the correct way to test state changes in a React component?

### React Code:

```
    var NotificationCenter = React.createClass({

        getInitialState: function(){
            return {notifications:[]}
        },


        render: function() {            

                countContainerStyle = {
                    display: this.state.notifications.length > 0 ? '' : 'none'
                };


            return (
                <div id="pc-notification-center">
                    <span className="pc-notification-center-bell" >
                        B
                    </span>
                    <span className="pc-notification-count-container" style={countContainerStyle}>
                        <span className="pc-notification-count-circle">&#9679;</span>
                        <span className="pc-notification-count">{this.state.notifications.length}</span>
                    </span>
                </div>);
        }

    });

    return NotificationCenter;
});
```

### Test Code:

```
it('should set its notification count to the number of notifications it has', function() {
        var notificationCenter = NotificationCenter({}),
            countNode;

        TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(notificationCenter);

        notificationCenter.setState({
            notifications: [1,2]
        });


        countNode = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(notificationCenter,'pc-notification-count');


        expect(countNode).toBe(2);
    });
```

### Edit: Full stack Trace

```
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Linux) [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] should default its notification count to 0 FAILED
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'deepestAncestor.firstChild')
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/bower_components/react/react.js:10314
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/bower_components/react/react.js:10260
    at getNode (/home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/bower_components/react/react.js:9874)
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/bower_components/react/react.js:4472
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/.tmp/notification_center/popover.js:28
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/bower_components/react/react.js:5925
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/.tmp/notification_center/popover.js:75
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/bower_components/react/react.js:5925
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/.tmp/notification_center/popover.js:81
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/bower_components/react/react.js:10461
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/bower_components/react/react.js:11924
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/bower_components/react/react.js:13944
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/bower_components/react/react.js:13877
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/bower_components/react/react.js:4360
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/bower_components/react/react.js:10055
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/bower_components/react/react.js:11169
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/bower_components/react/react.js:10105
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/bower_components/react/react.js:11169
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/.tmp/notification_center/notification_center.js:50
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/bower_components/react/react.js:10461
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/bower_components/react/react.js:11924
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/bower_components/react/react.js:13944
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/bower_components/react/react.js:13877
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/bower_components/react/react.js:4360
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/bower_components/react/react-with-addons.js:10483
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/bower_components/react/react-with-addons.js:11597
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/bower_components/react/react-with-addons.js:10533
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/bower_components/react/react-with-addons.js:11597
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/bower_components/react/react-with-addons.js:12716
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/test/notification_center/notification_center_test.js:19
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js:171
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:1585
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:841
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:1074
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:126
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:1117
    at each (/home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:58)
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:1118
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:895
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:1074
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:126
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:1117
    at each (/home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:58)
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:1118
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:895
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:1074
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:126
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:1117
    at each (/home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:58)
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:1118
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:895
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:1074
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:126
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:1117
    at each (/home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:58)
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:1118
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:895
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:1074
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:126
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:1117
    at each (/home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:58)
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:1118
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:895
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:1074
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:126
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:1117
    at each (/home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:58)
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:1118
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:895
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:1074
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:126
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:1117
    at each (/home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:58)
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:1118
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:895
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:1074
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:126
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:1117
    at each (/home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:58)
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:1118
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:895
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:1104
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:754
    at callGetModule (/home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:1129)
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:1479
    at /home/company/projects/user_interface_kit/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/require.js:1606
```

Here is a small project reproducing the issue
https://github.com/treehau5/react_karma_requirejs_bug_reproduction

Comment: Can you post more of the stack trace? Which line of your test causes the exception to be thrown?

Comment: A minimal repro case (in jsbin, etc) would be helpful; you shouldn't ever get that error. Feel free to file as a bug on the react repo.

Comment: I added the full stack trace.  The line that causes the exception is the .setState().  I get the same error if I update the state object manually and call forceUpdate() on the forceUpdate call.  It seems that this error happens when the component tries to re-render itself.

Comment: @BenAlpert I could not easily make a jsbin/fiddle, but I created a small project reproducing the issue. Pretty straightforward https://github.com/treehau5/react_karma_requirejs_bug_reproduction

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know if the previous answer is still true.

With React 0.11.1, this code works fine:

```
var React = require('react/addons');
var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;

jest.dontMock('public/components/MyThing.jsx');
var MyThing = require('public/components/MyThing.jsx');

describe('MyThing', function() {
  var html;

  describe('#render', function() {
    beforeEach(function(){
      var component = MyThing();
      var componentInstance = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(component);
      componentInstance.setState({isCool: true});

      html = componentInstance.getDOMNode().textContent;
    });

    it('includes something cool', function(){
      expect(html).toContain('something cool');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Can anyone verify if this still works with `0.12.*`?

Answer (score 2):

After digging deep into how React and React_with_addons works, it looks like the local React object in the test is different than the instance of React that React_with_addons uses.  So if you do this in your test:

```
react_with_addons.addons.TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(componentInstance);
```

Then react_with_addon's instance of React registers the componentInstance and primes its nodeCache object.  The local React instance remains is untouched.  Then, if you try to update the component's state like this:

```
componentInstance.updateState({key:'newValue'});
```

The local instance of React is used to try to update the DOM.  Because no components have ever been mounted with this instance, the update fails and you get the 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'deepestAncestor.firstChild') error.

Interestingly, if you mount ANY component into the local React, then you won't see an error when updating a component's state, even if that component was mounted using react_with_addon's React object.

The best way to avoid this problem for now, if your test needs to run setState, is to simply not use react_with_addon's renderIntoDocument function.  Instead, just create your own.  Its only two lines:

```
 function renderIntoDocument(instance) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        return React.renderComponent(instance, div);
      };
```

Comment: Is this still a valid hack? Or is there a good workaround now?

Comment: I'm going to guess this isn't valid anymore, since React has gone through many changes since this answer was written.

Answer (score 1):

You still can use original TestUtils.renderIntoDocument, only need to do is to move requiring React into beforeEach. Because if you require React globally, the context will be different for each test, which causes 2 different instances mount the same component.

```
beforeEach(function () {
    React = require('react/addons');
    TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;
});
```

Comment: This answer just saved me after nearly a week of debugging :)

Answer (score 0):

This is renderIntoDocument source code (React 0.14.8 I'm using in a project):
https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v0.14.8/src/test/ReactTestUtils.js#L79

And here's when it was changed - over 2 years ago: https://github.com/facebook/react/commit/ce95c3d042309d8aced894cc6be43d7e4cf96455

So despite the name it doesn't actually render anything into the document.

I can also confirm that Assaf's answer still works for 0.14.8 - basically, write your own renderIntoDocument. Here's what worked for me:

```js
function renderIntoDocument (instance) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    document.documentElement.appendChild(div);
    return ReactDOM.render(instance, div);
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, it might not make *their* tests fail, but it certainly did mine (because my code expected `element.ownerDocument.body.contains(element)` to return true for all rendered elements).